# Problem with Entity Framework Model Designer and SQL_Variant datatype

Tags: entity-framework, sql-variant

I have a table that has a column with SQL_Variant type and some other columns with types like int, bigint,...
When I add this table to edmx file it adds all columns but the SQL_Variant typed column.
Is there a bug or I have to do something to add that column?

Comment: and it is Nov 2018 - almost 10 years later the support is still not there in EF6.0 I am still getting Error 6005: The data type 'sql_variant' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version ... blah blah blah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [solution for read-only access](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_variant_in_ef.aspx).

Comment: Just to explain what the link provides without having to go there and read through it all...  The article shows a way to write an extension method to do a convert and get a concrete value rather than the complex_type that EF complains about.  It is read only because that conversion is one way.

Answer (score 5):

The entity framework doesn't support sql_variant. If you have to use that type in your code, you've to use another o/r mapper.